# Cocoapods lint error is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swift4

When I pod spec lint my private podspec, it gives me the error in the title.

I've this kind of code in one file:

```
class A {
  private let someVar = true
}

extension A {
  func someMethod() {
    print("\(someVar)")
  }
}
```

This was a problem with Swift 3 (I should've declared someVar as a fileprivate) but it's not more a problem in Swift 4 (I'm able to build correctly from Xcode) but for some reason pod lint complaints about it (cocoapods version 1.4.0)

Any clue why?

Answer (score 1):

Answering to myself :( maybe this can be useful to someone else in the future:

I still had the .swift_version file and it's deprecated in latest versions of cocoapods, in favour of adding this line into your podspec:

```
s.swift_version = '4.0'
```

(or whatever version you want to specify instead of 4.0)